# Encode filename multipart/form-data on wildfly 9

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, resteasy, multipartform-data

Sending a file with Czech characters UTF-8 encoded in filename (Žluťoučký kůň.txt), consumed by RESTEasy. But in java i always become US-ASCII filename (with is wrong of course)

HTML used to send file:

```
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="http://localhost/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

With is really sending:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAyBqNu6jIFHAB660
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Žluťoučký kůň.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Used filters for obtain UTF-8 encoding:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

 @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.setProperty(InputPart.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_PROPERTY, "*/*; charset=UTF-8");
        requestContext.setProperty(InputPart.DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY, "UTF-8");
```

Java code to read multipart:

```
 public List<CaseFile> uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input, long caseId) {
        MultipartFormDataOutput mdo = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();

    for (List<InputPart> inputParts : uploadForm.values()) {

        for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {
            try {

                // Retrieve headers, read the Content-Disposition header to obtain the original name of the file
                MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = inputPart.getHeaders(); //here are all headers in US-ASCII
```

and header contain:

> form-data; name="file"; filename="??lu??ou??k?? k????.txt"

Comment: Please clarify "//here are all headers in US-ASCII".

Comment: How are you viewing the headers? It's possible that your output stream doesn't support those characters. Please hexify your response in UTF-8, using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java

Comment: No, i have already tried such conversion - its really US-ASCII only

Comment: Sounds like you know it all already! Perhaps you've overlooked: [How can I get resteasy MultipartFormDataInput to decode strings using UTF-8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215733/how-can-i-get-resteasy-multipartformdatainput-to-decode-strings-using-utf-8)

Comment: I want to cry with happiness. The hack with reflection helps me.
`Field f = inputPart.getClass().getDeclaredField("bodyPart");
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    BodyPart bodyPart = (BodyPart) f.get(inputPart);
                    Header header = bodyPart.getHeader();
...
`

Comment: I presume you mean this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12512798/1554386 I notice it doesn't have any votes. I notice the answer has 0 votes so please up-vote the answer so people know it's good

Answer (score 2):

i use wildfly 9 with resteasy. The code above result in class cast exception for me. The code below solve my problem:

```
        Field field = inputPart.getClass().getDeclaredField("bodyPart");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object bodyPart = field.get(inputPart);
        Method methodBodyPart = bodyPart.getClass().getMethod("getHeader", new Class[]{});
        Iterable iterable = (Iterable)methodBodyPart.invoke(bodyPart, new Class[]{});
        Object[] content = IteratorUtils.toArray(iterable.iterator());
        Method methodContent = content[0].getClass().getMethod("getRaw", new Class[]{});

        String[] contentDisposition = methodContent.invoke(content[0], new Class[]{}).toString().split(";");

        for (String filename : contentDisposition) {
            if ((filename.trim().startsWith("filename"))) {

                String[] name = filename.split("=");

                String finalFileName = name[1].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
                return finalFileName;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This workaround worked for me with Wildfly 11 too! Thank you!